# jquery.payments TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I have the following issue:

Running ***Ruby on Rails 4.1.5***

**jquery.payments.js.coffee** is in vendor lib 
both *jquery.min* and *jquery.payments* are loaded correctly. (jquery payments after jquery.min)

I have a payment form with an input with the id "creditcard"

When I call in console:

```
$('#creditcard').payment('formatCardNumber');
```

I get:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

How can I make the input be restricted only to credit card digits?

Answer (score 0):

I was using jQuery 1.6.4
After upgrading to the latest jQuery version (1.11) this issue is not longer.